# How is the crowd in Madame Tussaud's Museum in Washington DC on Sundays?

Tags: museums, washington-dc

How long will it take on a normal Sunday (no special holiday or anything) to cover the Madame Tussaud's Museum?

Can we buy tickets on premise? Will there be a huge queue?

Comment: Google the site. Google should give you a sidebar (or on a phone, lead with this information) including general "busyness". Like Sunday at 3pm is called "usually a little busy".

Answer (score 1):

According to Google:

[image]

Sundays look busy in the afternoon, but free in the morning. You can buy tickets online for a [20% discount](https://www.madametussauds.com/washington-dc/en/tickets/) or get them on the spot. Unlike the museums in London or Amsterdam the Washington venue is not known for huge queues.